# Como ignorar maiúsculas e minúsculas no método Contains?

Tags: c#

Tenho duas `List` com algumas `strings`, por exemplo:

```
List<string> lista1 = new List<string>();
lista.Add("string1");
lista.Add("string2");
lista.Add("STRING3");

List<string> lista2 = new List<string>();
lista.Add("STRING1");
lista.Add("STRING2");
lista.Add("string3");
lista.Add("STRING4");
```

Preciso deletar da lista2, todas as strings que existem na lista1, ignorando se a letra é maiúscula ou minúscula.

Tenho esse código:

```
for (int i = lista2.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (lista1.Contains(lista2[i]))
        listMensagem.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

Mas isso não ignora as letras maiúsculas e minúsculas. Tentei usar o `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` mas o método `Contains` não aceita.

Nesse exemplo que dei, a lista2 teria que ficar somente com a `STRING4` como posso fazer isso?

Comment: não tem como com contains, você pode igualar as duas strings com toupper ou tolower, ou você pode trocar o contains por um indexof

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize o método `RemoveAll` com uma expressão para comparação:

```
lista2.RemoveAll(item1 => lista1.Any(item2 => item2.Equals(item1, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)));
```

Não se esqueça de incluir o namespace `System.Linq`.

Comment: coloquei no fiddle para facilitar a visualização: https://dotnetfiddle.net/qtBns9